# Editable cell of WPF Datagrid goes disabled on removing old value and putting blank and then tab out

Tags: wpf

I have problem with WPF datagrid.

One column of my datagrid is editable means I have put its property to `IsReadOnly="False"`.

But, if I make it blank by pressing back space key and tabout and again click on editable field but, then it is not editable. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and and solved this problem with the following approach:

I took "PreviewKeyDown" event in the grid and in this event I wrote the following code:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
                    {
                        myGrid.CancelEdit();
                    }
```

Actually, On editing mode cell expect some value, but if user keeps it blank then Cell Edit mode remains open. So, other cell was not opening in the edit mode.